# No result defined for action net.action.RegisterAction and result input

Tags: java, struts

```
<s:form action="register.action">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="head">Registration</div>
        <hr>
        <div>
            <label>Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="username"/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>User Id</label>
            <input type="text" name="userid"/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password"/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Email</label>
            <input type="text" name="email"/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>City</label>
            <input type="text" name="city"/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Locality</label>
            <input type="text" name="Locality"/>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" class="check"><div class="text">I confirm that I am 18 years or older & eligible to register and post ads</div>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox1">
            <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" class="check"><div class="text">Uncheck this box, if you do not wish to be intimated about special offers and new features.</div>
        </div>
        <div class="terms">By clicking " Register ", you're agreeing to our <a href="">Terms of Use & Privacy Policy.</a></div>
        <div>
            <button type="reset" id="reset">Reset</button>
            <s:submit value="Register" cssClass="submit-go" />
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</s:form>
```

---

#### Register.java

```
package net.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="Register")
public class Register {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;
@Column(name="username")
private String username;
@Column(name="userid")
private String userid;
@Column(name="password")
private String password;
@Column(name="email")
private String email;
@Column(name="city")
private String city;
@Column(name="locality")
private String locality;
public Register() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
public Register(int id, String username, String userid, String password,
        String email, String city, String locality) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.username = username;
    this.userid = userid;
    this.password = password;
    this.email = email;
    this.city = city;
    this.locality = locality;
}
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}
public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}
public String getUserid() {
    return userid;
}
public void setUserid(String userid) {
    this.userid = userid;
}
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}
public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}
public String getCity() {
    return city;
}
public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}
public String getLocality() {
    return locality;
}
public void setLocality(String locality) {
    this.locality = locality;
}
}
```

---

#### Register Action Class

```
 package net.action;

 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.List;

 import javax.persistence.Column;

 import net.controller.Manager;
 import net.model.Register;

 import com.opensymphony.xwork2.Action;
 import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

 public class RegisterAction extends ActionSupport{

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private String username;

private String userid;

private String password;

private String email;

private String city;

private String locality;

private List<Register> registerList;

public RegisterAction() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getUserid() {
    return userid;
}

public void setUserid(String userid) {
    this.userid = userid;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getCity() {
    return city;
}

public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}

public String getLocality() {
    return locality;
}

public void setLocality(String locality) {
    this.locality = locality;
}

public List<Register> getRegisterList() {
    return registerList;
}

public void setRegisterList(List<Register> registerList) {
    this.registerList = registerList;
}

public String execute() throws Exception {
    Register registerUser = new Register();
    String result = "error";
    List<Register> getUserdetails = new ArrayList<Register>();
    registerUser.setUsername(username);
    registerUser.setUserid(userid);
    registerUser.setPassword(password);
    registerUser.setEmail(email);
    registerUser.setCity(city);
    registerUser.setLocality(locality);

    if(Manager.adduser(registerUser)){
        getUserdetails = Manager.registerlist();
        return Action.SUCCESS;
    }
    return result;
}
```

### }

#### struts.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN" 
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
```

```
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="false"/>

 <package name="default" extends="struts-default">

 <action name="postad" method="execute" class="net.action.PostAction" >
        <result name="success" >viewpost.jsp</result>
        <result name="error" >postad.jsp</result>
    </action>

  <action name="register" class="net.action.RegisterAction" method="execute">
    <result name="SUCCESS">home.jsp</result>
    <result name="error">register.jsp</result>
  </action>
 </package>
```

I am doing a sample project  on struts2-Hibernate, when I am click on submit button then I found a error of

> HTTP Status 404 - No result defined for action net.action.RegisterAction and result input

please help me? What is the mistake here?

Answer (score 0):

first of all excuse my poor English.
On your jsp, try to use the defined struts tags instead html elements, the struts tags provide more information in case an error occurs. Also try to add the tags  actionError and actionMessage to visualize some error.

```
<s:form action="register.action">
   <s:textfield name="username" label="Name" />
   <s:textfield name="userid" label="User Id" />
   <s:password name="password" label="Password" />
   <s:submit value="Register" cssClass="submit-go" />
   <s:actionerror label="ERRORS" />
   <s:actionmessage label="MESSAGES" />
</s:form>
```

> HTTP Status 404 - No result defined for action net.action.RegisterAction and result input

This Error is generated the most of the time by de Workflow Interceptor, whenever occurs a Validation error before the Action execution
To see this Validation Error, on your action add a result with the name input.

```
<action name="register" class="net.action.RegisterAction" method="execute">
  <result name="SUCCESS">home.jsp</result>
  <result name="error">register.jsp</result>
  <result name="input">register.jsp</result>
</action>
```